# IE8 not starting app after upgrade from Ember 1.10 to 1.13.2

Tags: ember.js

After upgrading from 1.10 to 1.13.2 my application stopped working on IE8 - it doesn't load the main route and doesn't start the application correctly. There are no exceptions thrown. Below is the log from IE8:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember  : 1.13.2+616f7a7e
DEBUG: jQuery : 1.11.1
DEBUG: -------------------------------
Processing last blocks: 0ms
Timer "Processing last blocks" does not exist.
Attempting URL transition to /
generated -> route:application, [object Object]
generated -> route:index, [object Object]
Preparing to transition from '' to ' index'
Transition #0: application: calling beforeModel hook
Transition #0: application: calling deserialize hook
Transition #0: application: calling afterModel hook
Transition #0: index: calling beforeModel hook
Transition #0: index: calling deserialize hook
Transition #0: index: calling afterModel hook
Transition #0: Resolved all models on destination route; finalizing 
transition.
generated -> controller:application, [object Object]
generated -> controller:index, [object Object]
Transitioned into 'index'
Transition #0: TRANSITION COMPLETE.
```

And the same log from Chrome:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember  : 1.13.2+616f7a7e
DEBUG: jQuery : 1.11.1
DEBUG: -------------------------------
1360
Processing last blocks: 0.009ms
Ember Inspector Active
Attempting URL transition to /
generated -> route:events.index Object {fullName: "route:events.index"}
Preparing to transition from '' to ' events.index'
Transition #0: application: calling beforeModel hook
Transition #0: application: calling deserialize hook
Transition #0: application: calling afterModel hook
Attempting transition to events.country
Transition #0: events.index: transition was aborted
Transition #1: events: calling beforeModel hook
Transition #0: detected abort.
Transition #1: events: calling deserialize hook
Transition #1: events: calling afterModel hook
Transition #1: events.country: calling beforeModel hook
Transition #1: events.country: calling deserialize hook
Transition #1: events.country: calling afterModel hook
Transition #1: Resolved all models on destination route; finalizing 
transition.
generated -> controller:application Object {fullName: "controller:application"}
Deprecations were detected, see the Ember Inspector deprecations tab for more details.
Transitioned into 'events.country'
Transition #1: TRANSITION COMPLETE.
```

Before the upgrade everything worked fine. Any ideas?

Comment: According to [this page](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/04/20/ie8-support-update.html) Ember 1.13 does support IE8, so you should be okay with it. However they are planning to remove IE8 support in Ember 2.0, which will be the next major release so you need to be planning ahead for that. In the meanwhile, have you tried going back to 1.12? It's always possible there might be an issue in recent releases that hasn't been picked up yet.

Comment: I probably will consider that if I can't find a solution to this issue

Comment: Do any of [these](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_notable-breaking-changes-in-ember-2-0) apply to your application?